# Find No of Rows Having Value less than the value of present row

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Imagine I have A table that looks like this:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.2 |

I need to update the count_less_than column as the no of rows which have less value than current row value.

Output table would be like this:

| id | value | count_less_than |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.2 | 1 |

what would be query???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your MySQL version support `ROW_NUMBER` window function

You can try to use `ROW_NUMBER` window function with subtraction one

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY value) - 1 count_less_than
FROM T
ORDER BY ID;
```

| id | value | count_less_than |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.2 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qv1ffufxkfUnw9oDNEhoST/0)

if your MySQL version didn't support `ROW_NUMBER` window function

you can try to use subquery with `count` to calculate number

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM T tt
       WHERE tt.value < t.value) count_less_than
FROM T t
ORDER BY ID;
```

| id | value | count_less_than |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0.2 | 1 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qv1ffufxkfUnw9oDNEhoST/2)

Comment: SQL Error [1305] [42000]: FUNCTION ROW_NUMBER does not exist . Got this when i tried. Seems like mysql version doesnot support this function.

Comment: @SudipAdhikari I had added another version which didn't support window function

Comment: what if i need to alter table and add new column as that resulted column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated sub-query:

```
select *, (select Count(*) from t t2 where t2.value < t.value ) Count_Less_Than
from t;
```